# Replace Cassandra seed node after hardware failure on same machine?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have two VMs, each hosting a Cassandra seed node.  I wipe one VM to simulate a hardware failure.  I reinstall Cassandra and add `replace_address_first_boot` the end of the `cassandra-env.sh` file (with my real ipaddress)

```
 JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.replace_address_first_boot=1.1.1.1"
```

`nodetool status` on the other machine lists this machine as `DN`

`cassandra.yaml` displays the default value of `auto_bootstrap: true`

Yet, Cassandra startup fails with:

```
ERROR [main] 2022-02-24 01:43:36,546 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Replacing a node without bootstrapping risks invalidating consistency guarantees as the expected data may not be present until repair is run. To perform this operation, please restart with -Dcassandra.allow_unsafe_replace=true
```

How can I bootstrap the new seed machine even though it has the same ipaddress as the old seed machine without using an `unsafe` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, seed nodes don't stream upon joining.  My advice would be to remove its IP from the `seeds` in the `cassandra.yaml`.  Then upon joining, it should be fine.

If you still want it to be a seed node, you can always edit its `seeds` property with its own IP and restart once bootstrapping is complete.

Otherwise, if you can get the replacement node to start (without bootstrapping), you can always run a `nodetool repair` to stream the data.  The drawback here though, is that the node will try to serve requests *during* this process, so you may want to run `nodetool disablebinary` on it to prevent that (and of course re-enable it when done).

Comment: How do you know when bootstrapping is complete?

Comment: @patrick While bootstrapping, the node should be in a status of Up/Joining (`UJ`).  Once bootstrapping completes, it should be Up/Normal (`UN`).   You should also be able to monitor this activity by doing a `nodetool netstats`.